# wordpress do_action after loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, action, buddypress

i am working on a wordpress(3.3.1) site with a buddypress plugin. i am new to wordpress and i have some knowledge gaps when it comes to hook actions, but i have been programming in php for several years.

my question comes in reference to adding some of my logic after a wordpress/buddypress loop. in particular, i would like to add my logic at this point in a call:

`<?php do_action( 'bp_after_profile_edit_content' ); ?>`

as i said, my understanding is limited, because i thought i could just add a function in the functions.php file with the name "bp_after_profile_edit_content" that could just echo whatever i wanted. i have found out that is not the case.

thus, i would like to ask for some clarification on the topic. maybe a useful link. i am still trying to understand the codex as far as wp actions go.

Comment: never mind - figured it out; i forgot to add_action

Answer (score 0):

I noticed You've figured it out, but i'll answer it in case someone else finds this in the future with a similar issue. :)

```
function stackoverflow_example_action() { //unique function name
echo 'This text will echo'; //something to do.
} //lets end the function...
add_action( 'bp_after_profile_edit_content', 'stackoverflow_example_action' ); //now we need to add_action so that WordPress knows where to add it.
```

That will echo the text when 'bp_after_profile_edit_content' is being done.

Add Action: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action